# Taking the PMF to find the CDF, probability.

Tags: probability

Question:We toss a fair coin three times. Let X be the number of heads minus the number of tails obtained.
Write the cumulative distribution function of X.

What I already know: I know how to get the pmf from this problem.

$$
\ P(X=x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
   \ {3 \choose 0} (1/2)^3 & \quad \text{for $k = -3$}\\
   {3 \choose 1} (1/2)^3 & \quad \text{for $k = -1$}\\
   {3 \choose 2} (1/2)^3 & \quad \text{for $k = 1$}\\
   {3 \choose 3} (1/2)^3 & \quad \text{for $k = 3$}\\
  \end{array} \right.
$$

I'm not sure how my professor got this cdf:

$$
\ P(X \le x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
   \ 0 & \quad \text{for $x \lt -3$}\\
   (1/2)^3 & \quad \text{for $-3 \le x \lt -1$}\\
   (1+3) (1/2)^3 & \quad \text{for $-1 \le x \lt 1$}\\
   (1+3+3) (1/2)^3 & \quad \text{for $1 \le x \lt 3$}\\
   (1+3+3+1)(1/2)^3 & \quad \text{for $3 \le x$}\\
  \end{array} \right.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c.d.f. is not $x\mapsto \Pr(X=x)$; it is $x\mapsto\Pr(X\le x)$.  So, for example, its value at $x=2$ is $\Pr(X\le 2) = \Pr(X=-3) + \Pr(X=-1) + \Pr(X=1)$.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo!  I understand the portion where for $x \lt -3 $, etc. But the part I'm not understanding is when he says $(1+3)(1/2)^3$

Comment: You have the finite sequence $\dbinom 3 0,\ \dbinom 3 1,\ \dbinom 3 2,\  \dbinom 3 3$.  That's the same as $1,3,3,1$.  So the cumulative sum is as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
\text{coefficient} & \text{cumulative sum} \\
\hline 1 & 1 \\
3 & 1+3 \\
3 & 1+3+3 \\
1 & 1+3+3+1
\end{array}
$$